# How to properly set up HTTPS/SSL on MEAN stack application using Nginx

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, https, mean-stack

I am trying to accomplish having my URL endpoints (ex: https://www.busoutlaughing.com:443/api/nextshow) to work after I have installed CertBot (SSL/HTTPS) on my MEAN stack web app using NGINX.  I am using UBUNTU 18.04 server.

I can visit my URL www.busoutlaughing.com and see that it is using HTTPS:// in the address bar.

Now I would like to be able to hit the above API endpoint using HTTPS but must be missing something in configuration somewhere.

The error I am receiving is a 404 when trying to hit the endpoint:
'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)'

Here is what I have in code right now.. If I am missing any information please let me know, I think what is provided is all that is needed to understand my current setup.

All help is appreciated!

From app.js (node server code)

```
//importing modules
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');
var path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
var https = require('https')
const fs = require('fs');

var app = express();

const route = require('./routes/route');

...

//port number
const port = 80;

//adding midleware - cors
app.use(cors());

//body - parser
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyparser.json());

//static files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//routes
app.use('/api', route);

//testing server
app.get('/',(req, res)=>{
    res.send('foobar');
});

/*  -- Used to have this before doing HTTPS
app.listen(80,()=>{
    console.log('Server started at port: 80');
});
*/

// Certificate
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/busoutlaughing.com/privkey.pem', 'utf8');
const certificate = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/busoutlaughing.com/cert.pem', 'utf8');
const ca = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/busoutlaughing.com/chain.pem', 'utf8');

const credentials = {
    key: privateKey,
    cert: certificate,
    ca: ca
};

const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);


httpServer.listen(80, () => {
    console.log('HTTP Server running on port 80');
});

httpsServer.listen(443, () => {
    console.log('HTTPS Server running on port 443');
});
```

From route.js (API endpoints)

```
...

//Find the next available show
router.get('/nextshow', (req, res, next)=>{

logic here..

    })
});

...
```

From my performers.service.ts (angular service file)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Show } from './show';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PerformersService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  //get list of shows to sign up form
  getNextShow()
  {
    return this.http.get<Show>('https://www.busoutlaughing.com:443/api/nextshow');
  }
}
```

From my nginx server block under nginx/sites-available/

```
server {

        root /var/www/busoutlaughing.com/html/busoutlaughing;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name busoutlaughing.com www.busoutlaughing.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/busoutlaughing.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/busoutlaughing.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = www.busoutlaughing.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = busoutlaughing.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name busoutlaughing.com www.busoutlaughing.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer ended up being that I needed to change the port of the HTTP and HTTPS server (in the NodeJS code).  Nginx was using 80 already and also 443 for HTTP and HTTPS respectively.  I changed the port for HTTP back to 3000 and HTTPS (backend call, what I was trying to achieve) to 4430 and everything worked again.

```
httpServer.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('HTTP Server running on port 3000');
});

httpsServer.listen(4430, () => {
    console.log('HTTPS Server running on port 4430');
});
```